# cannot includ a existing file - failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, include

***this is not a duplicate question,  I read all related questions, and didn't find my answer.***

I want to include a file that exists :

`/var/www/html/monitor/protected/extensions/curl/curl.php`

and my code is :

`include('/monitor/protected/extensions/curl/curl.php');`

and I'm getting this error :

`include(/var/www/html/monitor/protected/extensions/curl/curl.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

and the file has 777 permission.

**My question is :**

is it possible that a file exists and have a 777 permission and a proper `chown` AND still give this error?

**Update :** I had used all three possible ways :

1. `include('/monitor/protected/extensions/curl/curl.php');`
2. `include('monitor/protected/extensions/curl/curl.php');`
3. `include('/var/www/html/monitor/protected/extensions/curl/curl.php');`

Im using php 5.3

**Note:** ***when including another file in the same directory, it includes without any problem***

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory?

Comment: my html and all of its sub directories have 777 permission

Comment: Try a relative path instead. `include('monitor/protected/extensions/curl/curl.php');` or `include('../monitor/protected/extensions/curl/curl.php');` depending on where your starting folders are.

Comment: Btw, `0777` is not the safest of permissions. If at all try using either `0755` or `0644` --- `0777` is a last resort.

Comment: I know, I'm in production mode

Comment: Then try `<?php include __DIR__ . "/monitor/protected/extensions/curl/curl.php"; ?>` @AlirezaFallah

Comment: And look into [`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) which may help.

Comment: believe me, I tried all of the above

Comment: Most bizarre. You're running this via `localhost` I presume. Can you access the file directly from your browser? And what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump(file_exists($file), is_readable($file), sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)));` where `$file` is your file's path?

Comment: @lafor bool(true) bool(false) string(6) "100777"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong path. If the file exists at

```
/var/www/html/monitor/protected/extensions/curl/curl.php
```

Then you should include that exact string.

```
include('/var/www/html/monitor/protected/extensions/curl/curl.php');
```

`/` means the root of the file system. You get permission denied because you most certainly don't have permission to `/` and `/monitor` doesn't exist

Alternatively you can include it relatively. By dropping the first `/` you would do:

```
include('monitor/protected/extensions/curl/curl.php');
```

This will work if the running script is also in `/var/www/html`.

I think you're getting confused at the difference between the HTTP path and the system path. PHP files are included from the system path and should be referenced by the system path.

Comment: I believe the OP already tried `include('/monitor/protected/extensions/curl/curl.php');`

Comment: I just posted what he posted.

Comment: I also did mention [in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723116/cannot-includ-a-existing-file-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied#comment31045706_20723116) about using a relative path. Btw, I did not downvote this. (I never downvote answers) *It's not my style*

Comment: It wasn't completely clear. I was trying to show why what he was doing was wrong. Edited to clarify.

Comment: `/` strats from `/var/www/html` . you are so wrong . and by the way , I tested the relative path, as I mentioned in the comments

Comment: / that starts from /var/www/html is a URL. So you can do something like /index.html as a URL. But PHP includes work off the system path.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late, but I just want to confirm Alireza Fallah's answer. This also worked for me. It looks like it has to be the original owner. So unzip/unrar the php files on the same machine you want to use it on. Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope - not for me - same error - both accessing file and common.php have the same owner (me) and Details. Also, unzipped on server. Juts for anyone else battling with this.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the file, and created again, and my problem solved.

the original file was downloaded from the internet and unzipped from a zipped file.

**I think** there was a problem with creating the file by original author.

This is very odd! but it worked